# Retrieve values from converted JSON using Angular 5/Typescript

Tags: json, xml, angular, typescript

I have just retrieved an object using **SOAP** and **HTTPClient** from Angular5 and i'm having issues to retrieve specific values.
The thing is, I can access only all of them using:

```
         import {parseString} from 'xml2js';
         ...

         parseString(data, function (err, result) {
           var stringified = JSON.stringify(result);
           console.log(stringified);

          }
```

For example **below is the XML converted to JSON** that I have. I have two questions:

**1) How would I retrieve the specific << values >> inside of it?**
Like **id**, **name**, **event** ... **InSpec**, **OutSpec**, **MiddleSpec** and else?

```
{
    "soap:Envelope": {
        "$": {
            "xmlns:soap": "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope",
            "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
            "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        },
        "soap:Body": [{
            "List": [{
                "$": {
                    "xmlns": "http://WebService/"
                },
                "ListResult": [{
                    "Total": ["1"],
                    "Dados": [{
                        "Posicao": [{
                            "id": ["<<value>>"],
                            "name": ["<<value>>"],
                            "event": ["<<value>>"],
                            "address": ["<<value>>"],
                            "description": ["<<value>>"],
                            "addressid": ["<<value>>"],
                            "number": ["<<value>>"],
                            "city": ["<<value>>"],
                            "descriptionEvent": ["<<value>>"],
                            "lat": ["<<value>>"],
                            "long": ["<<value>>"],
                            "In": [{
                                "InSpec": [{
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["true"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }]
                            }],
                            "Out": [{
                                "OutSpec": [{
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["false"]
                                }]
                            }],
                            "Middle": [{
                                "MiddleSpec": [{
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["506"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["0"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["0"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["8"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["0"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["12.54"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["4658"]
                                }, {
                                    "Descricao": ["<<value>>"],
                                    "Valor": ["4.1"]
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

**2) Is it better to convert from XML to JSON to retrieve these values or is it possible to get them directly from XML?**

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If the result is a json object, then you should be able to access it using json['keyAsString'] but i think you shall have to do multiple iterations to get the values you need. What does console.log(result) show?

Comment: What should I pass to JSON['keyAsString']?

Comment: what does console.log(result) show?. Should be result['field name as shown in result object']

Comment: It returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a stringified json. This works

```
let jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringified);
console.log('jsonObject', jsonObject);
let jsonEnvelope = jsonObject['soap:Envelope'];
let jsonBody = jsonEnvelope['soap:Body'];
console.log(jsonBody);
let jsonList = jsonBody[0];
console.log(jsonList);
let jsonListResult = jsonList['List'];
console.log(jsonListResult);
```

Of course a proper answer would be to create a mapper and proper models for your soap response.

Comment: That means I should recreate a variable for each row I would want to jump in? Do you think this is a good way to do this?

Comment: As I said a proper solution would require a json mapper. Like here http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/. Or you can use an npm package for that, there are some out there. But this one works if you exactly where your data is and is not deep inside the response.